# Apexchart - How to get a line chart with grouped x-axis labels

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apexcharts

I want to draw a line chart with grouped X-axis labels, like this bar chart example https://apexcharts.com/react-chart-demos/column-charts/column-with-group-label/

I want to create groups of 10 elements each, so I do the following in the options object:

```
const options = {
  xaxis: {
    group: {
      groups: [
        { title: '2020', cols: 10 },
        { title: '2021', cols: 10 },
        { title: '2022', cols: 10 }
      ]
    }
  },
}
```

When I try this with a bar chart, it works fine, but when I change to a line chart, it doesn't work and the axis labels are shown without the groups.

I'm using apexcharts with react.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when showing bars combined with lines, I solved it by adding the property `tickPlacement`:

```json
const options = {
  xaxis: {
    tickPlacement: 'between',
    group: {
      groups: [
        { title: '2020', cols: 10 },
        { title: '2021', cols: 10 },
        { title: '2022', cols: 10 }
      ]
    }
  },
}
```

https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/xaxis/